# Dividing pandas dataframe column into n buckets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 7 columns. For one of these columns, I want to divide its content into n-buckets depending only on the values. So, if my column has values `1, 3, 5 ... (2*n+1)` , I add a new column with buckets as `1,2,3...n`.

Also, I'm not looking to normalize in the sense that even if I have a 100 3's in the column, I want them in the same bucket. So, if I have `1, 3, 3, 3, 5, ... (2*n+1)`, my output would be `1, 2, 2, 2, 3, .. n`.

Can someone please guide me how to do it.

--edit--

My actual data has more than a million rows. So, if I use rank I get a rank from a 1 to a million. What I want is to divide the ranks into buckets. So for example if I have 3 million rows and end up with ranks from 1 to 1.5 million. If I want to divide it into 3 buckets, 1 get first bucket with first 0.5 million rank, 2nd bucket with the next half million and so on. Similarly if I want to divide it into 7 buckets.

Regards

Comment: Sorry, for me it is a bit unclear. Can you add another sample with desired output?

Comment: @jezrael, sure. So if the input column is `1,5,3,9,5,3,7,10` then the output column should have `1,3,2,5,3,2,4,6` as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,5,3,9,5,3,7,10]})
print (df)
   col
0    1
1    5
2    3
3    9
4    5
5    3
6    7
7   10

df['col1'] = df.col.rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print (df)
   col  col1
0    1     1
1    5     3
2    3     2
3    9     5
4    5     3
5    3     2
6    7     4
7   10     6
```

EDIT: I think you need floor division `//`:

```
n = 3
df['col1'] = np.arange(len(df.index)) // n
print (df)
   col  col1
0    1     0
1    7     0
2    3     0
3    3     1
4    5     1
5    7     1
6   13     2
```

If monotonic increasing index like `0,1,2...n`:

```
n = 3
df['col1'] = df.index // n
print (df)
   col  col1
0    1     0
1    7     0
2    3     0
3    3     1
4    5     1
5    7     1
6   13     2
```

Comment: Sorry, you need `1,4,2,2,3,4,5` ?

Comment: I deleted my comment, that was in response to your first answer. I'm checking this asnwer against my inputs !

Comment: No problem, now it get your desired output.

Comment: Wonderful, it works for the rank and I've checked it against my input and it works flawlessly. But I had another question. So, now for the input you've provided, suppose I want to divide the input into 3 buckets. How do i get it? My actual input is more than a million line in the dataframe which I want to divide into 5, 7, and 9 buckets. For a small input, this is equivalent to rank, but not for a huge input. can you please help.

Comment: I add another edit, but it is what you need? Or combination `rank` and floor division?

Answer (score 4):

Pandas has function `cut()` for this sort of binning:

```
data=pd.Series([1,3,3,3,5,7,13])
n_buckets = (data.max() - data.min()) // 2 + 1
buckets = pd.cut(data, n_buckets, labels=False) + 1
#0    1
#1    2
#2    2
#3    2
#4    3
#5    4
#6    7
```